# How do you escape a double-colon in a DOS batch file?

Tags: batch-file, escaping, dos

I need to run a command in a DOS batch file that contains a double colon AND set the output to a variable.  Like this

```
set /a TDR = C:\InCharge\CONSOLE\smarts\bin\dmctl -s SSA-SAM invoke SM_System::SM-System nameToAddr %SM_OBJ_InstanceName%
```

I keep getting "Missing operator".  I assume that is due to those double-colons. How do I escape these?  I tried back-slashes but that didn't work.  I've tried putting the whole command in double-quotes and that also didn't work.

I can run the command by itself, ie without the "set /a TDR" and the output is correct. But I need to use that output as the value of a variable hence the "set /a"

Normal output for dmctl is this

```
{ "10.28.112.74" }
```

I am using dmctl to get the ip address for the hostname.  I figured once I got the output I could strip off the brackets and quotations, but I haven't figured out how to grab the output.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: According to http://ss64.com/nt/set.html, you can only use /a for arithmetic functions...

Comment: Please provide an output sample of your `dmctl` command. Your problem is simply solvable using `for /F` loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Colons do not need to be escaped.  See [Batch files - Escape Characters](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/escapechars.php) for details on what characters need to be escaped, and how to escape them.

"Missing operator" is being returned because `SET /A` only works with arithmetic operations, so it is looking for an arithmetic operator.

To assign the output of a command to a variable, you have to use the FOR command, similar to the following:

```
for /f  "delims=" %%i in ('C:\InCharge\CONSOLE\smarts\bin\dmctl -s SSA-SAM invoke SM_System::SM-System nameToAddr %SM_OBJ_InstanceName%') do set myresult=%%i
```

See [Reading the output of a command into a batch file variable](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2012/07/31/10334556.aspx)

To trim 3 characters from the beginning and end of a string:

```
set mystring=%mystring:~3,-3%
```

This will remove the curly braces, spaces, and quotation marks that delimit the IP address in the output.

I found this at [DOS - String Manipulation](http://www.dostips.com/DtTipsStringManipulation.php).

Comment: Thanks. That is a good reference. See my edit above. I have to strip off the brackets and the quote marks.  I find this "for /f" syntax to be completely baffling. I'm a unix shell and perl scripter and I can not get my head around the dos syntax.

Comment: The FOR command is the most bizarre thing ever.  I don't recommend that anyone use it unless they have no other option.  Powershell is much easier and far more powerful...